# Even values from lists into a set

Tags: python, list, set

Here is the given assignment + code:

> Write a function `even_value_set(list1, list2, list3)`, which receives
> three lists containing integer items as arguments. The function
> creates and returns a set that contains all items with even value from
> all three lists.

```
def test():
    l = [[],[],[]]
    
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(random.randint(7,14)):
            l[i].append(random.randint(1,35))
        print ("List" + str(i + 1) +":",l[i])
        
    print ("")
    s = even_value_set(l[0],l[1],l[2])
    print ("Return type:", str(type(s)).replace("<","").replace(">",""))
    print ("Set with even values only:", end = "")
    print (set(sorted(list(s))))
    
test()

import random
```

I tried using .union() and making adding lists into another before turning them into sets, but didn't have any luck.

Comment: You are asking for help with `even_value_set()` but you haven't  shown us the function you wrote. Saying *I tried using `.union()` and making adding lists into another before turning them into sets* does not make clear where the problem lies. You're asking us to imagine what you have written and then tell you where the problem with it might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a simply pythonic way. This function can be written as a simple oneliner using comprehension

```
def even_value_set(list1, list2, list3):
    return set([num for num in list1+list2+list3 if num % 2 == 0])
```

Basically, what we did here is concatenated all lists, fitered even numbers and then made it into a set.

Comment: are there any undesired effect to do that `list1+list2+list3` concatenation (I m specifically thinking if the list are very very long)? Would it be safer to loop - at the expense of a couple of extra lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

You can union lists (with duplicates) with the + operation.

```
union_list = list1 + list2 + list3
```

If you only want the unique values you can call set on this list.

```
unique_set = set(union_list)
```

Now you can create a new empty set and iterate over the unqiue_set and add all the even values:

```
solution = set()
for v in unique_set:
    if v%2==0:
        solution.add(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def even_value_set(*lsts):
    s = set()
    for lst in lsts:
        s |= {x for x in lst if x % 2 == 0}
    return s
```

Also you can use starring

```
def even_value_set(*lsts):
    return set().union(*[{x for x in lst if x % 2 == 0} for lst in lsts])
```

And solution with concatenation (more memory).
set comprehension is more effective than `set()`

```
def even_value_set(l1, l2, l3):
    return {x for x in l1+l2+l3 if x % 2 == 0}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make the union of lists using `+`, like `list1 + list2`. Then just walk through the result list checking if the number is even and adding in another list.

```
def even_value_set(list):
  result = set()
  for val in list:
    if val%2 == 0:
      result.add(val)
  return result

def test():
l = [[],[],[]]

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(random.randint(7,14)):
        l[i].append(random.randint(1,35))
    print ("List" + str(i + 1) +":",l[i])
    
print ("")
uni = l[0] + l[1] + l[2]
s = even_value_set(uni)
print ("Return type:", str(type(s)).replace("<","").replace(">",""))
print ("Set with even values only:", end = "")
print (set(sorted(list(s))))

test()

import random
```

Is it what you want? I think your question is confusing.

Comment: Please add suggestions as comments, not answers

Comment: I can't comment yet

Comment: You can always edit and provide a valid anwer :-)

Comment: Yes, I did it, thank you